# Embed SVG icon into html

Tags: html, svg, favicon

I need embed my SVG icon directly into the html file, not as a link to an SVG file.

I have tried to add `<link>SVG file contents</link>` to the html but it didn't work.

My html's `<head>`:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#568342"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="My App"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icon_apple.png"/>
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png"/>
<title>My App</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why linking or using a shortcut does not work for you? The normal practice is to place them the following way:

`<link rel="mask-icon" href="icon.svg" color="blue">`
`<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg">` The masked icon is for iOS 9+ and pinned tabs.

Comment: Please check the [support for SVG favicons](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg)

Comment: i can only make one request, and i want the icon to be present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) as a value for the `href` attribute of the `<link>`. Like enxaneta remarked, the [compatibility data](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg) strongly suggest that you first convert the SVG to a PNG (easiest is exporting it from a vector grafics UI). After that you would convert it to a data url, for example with [this online tool](http://dataurl.net/).

If you insist on using the SVG directly, [this](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) online utility is better suited for SVGs, you can drop in the source text.

Your final result looks like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,...">
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,...">
```